# In matlab, increment different column element for every row in without using a loop

Tags: matlab

Assume you have an 4x4 matrix A of zeros:

```
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
```

And an 4x1 vector B that represents column indices for matrix A (so values [1:4])

```
4
2
3
1
```

Now I want to increment those columnpositions in matrix A on the index on every row from vector B.
I have tried a couple of constructions myself but can't quite manage to do this.

For example I tried:

```
A(:, B) = A(:, B)+1
```

Which just increment every element in A.

This is how I want the operation to act:

```
>> A(somethting(B)) = A(somethting(B)) + 1
0   0   0   1
0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using the linear index to each of the elements you want to address. Compute this using `sub2ind`:

```
>> A = zeros(4)

A =

     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0

>> B = [4 2 3 1]

B =

     4     2     3     1

>> i=sub2ind(size(A),B,1:4)

i =

     4     6    11    13

>> A(i) = A(i)+1

A =

     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Odd.. I actually tried that function but failed :p Must have done something wrong. Thank you for the help and example!

Answer (score 0):

Well just in case you want a looped version :p

```
A = zeros(4,4);
B = [4, 2, 3, 1];

for i = 1:length(B)

    A(i, B(i) ) = A(i, B(i) ) + 1;

end
```

Comment: Title: "... without using a loop"

Answer (score 0):

```
A = zeros(4);
B = [4 2 3 1];
A(repmat([1:4]',1,4) == repmat(B,4,1)) = 1

A =

 0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 1     0     0     0
```